# What Saints have given guided written meditations?

Tags: catholicism, saint, meditation

Recently I have found meditations by St. Francis de Sales in his Introduction to the Devout life, and St Ignatius Loyola in his Spiritual Exercises, that I find have helped to deepen my faith.  Are there any other guided written meditations by other Saints?  I am looking for something more in depth than a paragraph meditation, on that really helps you to meditate on the deeper meaning.

Comment: I deleted the "answerish" comments,  I do not think this question is too broad.  These particular works of St. Ignatius and St. Francis de Sales have been very popular  for hundreds of years and anyone familiar with them would know what similar writings Virginia is looking for.

Comment: "_I am looking for something more in depth than a paragraph meditation_" Then it seems you're looking for spiritual reading recommendations in general. See, for example, St. John of the Cross's [_Dark Night of the Soul_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/6159) or St. Teresa of Ávila's [_The Interior Castle_](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/6158).

Comment: I suggest you find an SSPX (or Traditional Catholic) parish near you who offers Ignatian Retreat! That's one great way to grow! Not only do you learn how to meditate, but also how to save your soul!

Answer (score 1):

The first book which comes in my mind at reading your question is "The Practice of the Love of Jesus Christ" of St. Alphonse de Liguori, that I highly recommand. The thoughts St Alphonse provide really deeps the faith. Furthermore, St Alphonse de Liguori likes to quote St Therese D'Avila, a very great catholic mystic. 
Meditations are not guided, but the structure of the text is a self-guidance.

For a really guided meditation (step 1, 2, etc.) I obvisously think to "The Imitation of the Christ" (De imitatione Christi) but you need to find one where text structure has been kept (Chapter X - Thinking)

Answer (score 0):

St. [John Eudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Eudes) wrote [The Admirable Heart of Mary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1896384056) may be of some interest to you. I read this work some 20 years ago and found it very enlightening. You could also read some of his works online: **Meditations on Various Subjects** by Saint John Eudes [here](http://www.liberius.net/livres/Meditations_on_various_subjects_000000345.pdf).